# Hosting and Speed Optimization solutions for very large listing WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, hosting, directory-listing

I have a WordPress listing website. The database has been reached to 25MBs, and site content is more than 12GBs. Site speed has gone terribly slow. What do you recommend for hosting solution and speed optimization?

Answer (score 0):

test your site speed on 
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
&
http://tools.pingdom.com/
this both sites are help you to find the reason of your speed related issue.

As per you mentioned your site content is more than 12GBs that means your site has may be too much images - below one of the plugin can be useful for you.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cache-images/